# isset($) double if/elseif/else. Can it cleaner?

Tags: php, coding-style

Okay, I got this code build up but i guess it is somehow ugly.
Can this been done better?

```
if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    if ($lang == 'en') {
        $_GET['method']($lang);
    }
    elseif ($lang == 'nl') {
        $_GET['method']($lang);
    }
    else {
        $_GET['method']($lang);
    }
}
else {
    $lang = '';
    $_GET['method']($lang);
}
```

Comment: If you allow for `index.php?method=eval&lang=whatever()` then you really shouldn't bother with `isset`.

Comment: you should worry about `isset` to prevent `array index not set` warnings. Or you could just ignore the warnings. But best practice is to use `isset` to avoid them.

Comment: @mario: Though your example would not work, cause eval isn't a function. Instead just use assert ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function GET($name, $default=null)
{
    if ( !isset($_GET[$name]) )
        return $default;
    return $_GET[$name];
}

$method = GET('method'); // Don't forget to error-check $method too, or it will be a major security hole!
$method(GET('lang',''));
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the major security hole in being able to specify arbitrary function names to be called, direct from the browser.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? :)

Anyway, just wanted to say, that besides this method my projects usually also have a GETint() method, which automatically checks whether the query parameter is an integer and casts it appropriately. Because integers are as common as strings in parameters. And, of course, the POST() and POSTint() counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you intend to `$_GET['method']($lang)` no matter what the value of $lang is. So don't check the value; just determine it, and then use it.

```
if (isset($_GET['lang'])) { $lang = $_GET['lang']; }
else { $lang = ''; }
$_GET['method']($lang);
```

Answer (score 0):

Won't

```
if (isset($_GET['lang'])){
$lang = $_GET['lang'];
if ($lang == 'en'){
    $_GET['method']($lang);
} elseif ($lang == 'nl'){
    $_GET['method']($lang);
} else {
    $_GET['method']($lang);
} 
} else {
    $lang = '';
    $_GET['method']($lang);
}
```

do exactly the same as

```
if (isset($_GET['lang'])){
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    $_GET["method"]($lang);
} else {
    $lang = '';
    $_GET['method']($lang);
}
```

@Highmastdon: To make the example complete see my correction

Comment: Oh wait, I'm sorry. I din't see that you excluded the first rule with isset. In that case you are right about this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling `$_GET['method']($lang);` in every case, including the `else`, you don't need all those conditions to do the same thing; the code you've given could be written as simple as this:

```
$lang = isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : '';
$_GET['method']($lang);
```

You could even combine those two lines into one like so:

```
$_GET['method'](isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : '');
```

...although that is starting to get a bit un-readable.

However, I would echo the point made by @Vilx- that calling a function name that is specified directly from the browser can be a **major** security risk, so you*really* need to vet the contents of `method` and `lang`. (imagine if the url looked like `?method=eval&lang=rm+index.php`)

Answer (score 0):

```
$_GET['method'](isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : '');
```

But please, please **please** don't do this. You have a massive security hole, if the user specifies `method=eval` (or any other function that you don't really want called).